speed control with torque/load balancing for tightly coupled cooperative motors
I'm working on a multi motor application where two or more motors are directly coupled through gearing to combine their output onto what is effectively a single output (multiple wheels on one side of a differential robot).
For velocity / speed control, the simple approach of applying a uniform feedforward(FF)+PI control input to all motor inputs works ok, but the loading on the motors is unbalanced which is wasteful.
Experimentally I came up with a scheme that assigns one motor (in reality the one that is reporting the lowest temperature) as the leading motor that gets the raw FF+PI based on the command (joystick) velocity and the averaged encoder velocity for the error term. The other (follower) motors then get the same FF term but now use a PI control based on the torque error reported between the leading motor and that specific motor's torque.
Researching this I've found a few papers that hint at the same methodology, which seems to validate this approach.
The challenge of course with anything PID related is coming up with a practical implementation and tuning approach. Rather than invest more time in this I was hoping that someone had already done this in some of the common ecosystems such as First or VEX as this does not seem like a new problem, but I'm having trouble finding something.
Any pointers appreciated - thanks.
